# Flickr JSON feed

Tags: php, json, flickr

Im trying to retrieve some json from Flickr, and use a foreach loop to display some specific data, just as ive done with delicious and twitter.
However the json it returns is formatted differently and it doesnt seem to work, any ideas guys? Thanks

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
        "title": "Recent Uploads tagged un",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/un/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2012-02-22T14:48:07Z",
        "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
        "items": [
       {
            "title": "PLAYA SOLITARIA",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/lomar_alv/6920550211/",
            "media": {"m":"http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7040/6920550211_516eb7ae13_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2009-08-25T18:34:25-08:00",
            "description":
```

Comment: What do you mean by *formatted differently* and *it doesn't seem to work*?

Comment: You have a big chunk of code there. What is it? I'm guessing it is some JSONP from Flickr. What code are you using to try to parse it?

Comment: It's invalid JSON. You have to ditch the jsonFlickrFeed( stuff.

Comment: Just in case somebody need it, working sample reading from Flickr Feed http://jsfiddle.net/Braulio/vDr36/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass options:

```
$options = array (
    'format' => 'json',
    'nojsoncallback' => 1
);
```

Comment: Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue. Please edit your answer to include a description *why* this solves the question.

Comment: I just came across this answer... and yeah... apparently it's an option in their api according to this link: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it

```
//Grab the feed
$json_feed = file_get_contents("http://www.WhateverTheFeedUrlIs.com");

//Decode it
$json_to_array = json_decode($json_feed);

//Print it out if you want
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_to_array);
echo '</pre>';

//Grab specific info
echo $json_to_array->title;  //Recent Uploaded Tags
echo $json_to_array->url; //http://www.flickr.com....
echo $json_to_array->items[0]->title; //PLAYA SOLITARIA
```

Comment: this is what ive been doing for the other sites, however in this instance when using the foreach loop to echo specific info it gives the error 'invalid argument supplied for foreach' so its not an array?

Comment: What do you mean it's not an array?  You can't do `foreach($json_to_array->items as $i) { echo $i->title;}`???

Comment: yea that doesnt work. also has an error saying that $json_to_array->items is trying to get property of non object

Answer (score 0):

I know it's dated but for anyone else wondering about this...do:

```
json_decode(ereg_replace("^jsonFlickrFeed\((.*)\)$", "\\1", stripslashes(strip_tags($STRING_YOU_GOT_BACK_FROM_FLICKR))));
```

That should clean up the response so json_decode() works. Also note you could put a true at the end there to return an array instead of an object with json_decode().

Actually, that's deprecated. You'll just want to do a similar regex with preg_replace(). Or even:

```
$responseString = str_replace(array("\n", "\t"), '', $STRING_BACK_FROM_CURL);
$responseString = stripslashes(strip_tags($responseString));
preg_match('/^jsonFlickrFeed\((.*)\)/i', $responseString, $matches);
$flickrJson = $matches[1];
$flickrObject = json_decode($flickrJson);
```